# PDO -> Why use fetchAll?

Tags: php, pdo

Suppose i'm querying my database with a simple SELECT statement.

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM products';
$s=$db->prepare($sql);
$s->execute();
foreach($s as $v){
   echo $v['productName'];
}
$s->closeCursor();
```

However i saw the following code, using fetchAll() to do the same:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM products';
$s=$db->prepare($sql);
$s->execute();
$products=$s->fetchAll();
$s->closeCursor();
foreach($products as $v){
   echo $products['productName'];
}
```

First of all, I know that fetchAll() shouldn't be used for large result sets.
However, the question is: **If we can directly transverse the PDOStatement object returned by the prepare() method why do we they make fetchAll() (and fetch())available?**

It seems that the only advantage will be free the connection earlier!

Comment: Have you tested both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple:
Because you have to **separate business logic from presentations logic.**
Means first you have to get all the required data and only then start the output.
And fetchAll become quite handy in this matter.

Well, after closer look at your question

> If we can directly transverse the PDOStatement object, why do they make fetchAll() (and fetch())available?

I think that such a "direct traversing" is merely a syntax sugar, having good old fetch() underneath or something like that.

Comment: And even when you are doing something simple in a single PHP file you might want to do some separation, like closing the cursor befor you go off writing stuff to files or a network that could crash.

Comment: Yes, in fact foreach will call fetch() underneath!

Comment: @FriedSmurf, that was actually the nature of my comment, since I didn't see any fetch() there.